# Insert array values in inputs with specific class, index by index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an array of strings. How can I put each value into each field in HTML, index by index?

```js
const pid = [ "688", "500", "450" ];
```

```html
<input type="text" class="field_pid">
<input type="text" class="field_pid">
<input type="text" class="field_pid">
```

Comment: You can use `map`.

Comment: Some closely related variations: Reaching the current element (and its properties): [How to reach the element itself inside jQuery’s `val`?](/q/16710521/4642212); Mapping the current value (e.g. via a function, or appending something to it): [Modify the value of each textfield based on original value using jQuery](/q/24725927/4642212), and [Append text to input field](/q/841722/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

Using [`val( function )`](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function)

> The .val() method allows setting the value by passing in a function.
>   As of jQuery 1.4, the function is passed two arguments, the current
>   element's index and its current value

```js
var pid = ["688", "500", "450"];

$(".field_pid").val((i) => pid[i]);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="field_pid">
<input type="text" class="field_pid">
<input type="text" class="field_pid">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. It works for me:

```js
$(function() {
  var pid = ['688', '500', '450'];
  var l = pid.length;
  var i = 0;
  while (i < l) {
    $('.field_pid').eq(i).val(pid[i]);
    i++;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="field_pid">
<input type="text" class="field_pid">
<input type="text" class="field_pid">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways either you can map over the classes because same class stored in array format or you have already array list **pid** , i maped over array **pid**

```js
var pid = ['688', '500', '450'];
$(document).ready(function(){
pid.map((value , key)=>{
$('.field_pid').eq(key).val(pid[key]);
})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input type="text" class="field_pid">
<input type="text" class="field_pid">
<input type="text" class="field_pid">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` and `eq`:

```js
$(() => {
  const pid = ["688", "500", "450"];
  
  pid.forEach((num, idx) => $(".field_pid").eq(idx).val(num));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="field_pid">
<input type="text" class="field_pid">
<input type="text" class="field_pid">
```